# Not a SCALAR reference at test.pl line 11

Tags: xml, perl

My script showing Not a scalar reference at line 11

My script is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
@files = <*.xml>;
foreach $file (@files) {#!/usr/bin/perl
# use module
use XML::Simple;
# create object
$xml = new XML::Simple;
# read XML file
$data = $xml->XMLin("$file");
# access XML data
foreach my $entry (@{$data->{result}->{entries}->{entry}}){
print "$file $data->{result}->{entries}->{entry}->{ip} $data->{result}->{entries}->{entry}->{mac}\n";
}}
```

and i have a xml files in a folder like below

I want to list all ips and mac addresses from all files, I am trying with foreach my $entry.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

-<response status="success">
  -<result>

     <max>1000</max>

     <total>2</total>

     <timeout>1800</timeout>

     <dp>dp0</dp>


    -<entries>


     -<entry>

        <status> c </status>

        <ip>10.0.0.1</ip>

        <mac>00:00:oo:88:70:41</mac>

        <ttl>1590</ttl>

        <interface>ethernet1/2</interface>

        <port>ethernet1/2</port>

      </entry>


      -<entry>

        <status> c </status>

        <ip>17.0.0.1</ip>

        <mac>00:0f:00:00:00:42</mac>

        <ttl>1500</ttl>

        <interface>ethernet1/4</interface>

        <port>ethernet1/4</port>

      </entry>

    </entries>

   </result>

 </response>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use [XML::Simple](http://p3rl.org/XML::Simple). Its documentation tells you

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged.

2. Use [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data::Dumper) to visualise complex data structures.

   ```
   use Data::Dumper;
   print Dumper($data);
   ```

   You'll see that `entry` is an array reference, not a hash. You need to say what element of the array you want:

   ```
   print $data->{result}{entries}{entry}[0]{ip}, ' ',
         $data->{result}{entries}{entry}[0]{mac}, "\n";
   ```

   or iterate over all of them:

   ```
   for my $entry (@{ $data->{result}{entries}{entry} }) {
       print $entry->{ip}, ' ', $entry->{mac}, "\n";
   }
   ```

   Note that arrows between square and curly brackets are optional.